# PSR-16 "cache" on disk implementation for PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

PhpSpreadhsheet takes a LOT of memory and I'm unable to reliably use it to generate big files on my 2gb server. I'm trying to find a way to cache on disk instead of RAM , the documentation says it is possible (https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/) but no implementation is given.

I found two github projects that implements a PSR-16 on disk - https://github.com/duncan3dc/cache
and
https://github.com/adinan-cenci/cache
but they didn't work for me (the second one I couldn't even Install)

Any implementations or workarounds to save the temporary files on disk or a way to generate big excels without a lot of memory?

Comment: You will find that PhpSpreadsheet becomes unusably slow with an on-disk cache. I tried it some time ago and it was not worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

Use php spout https://opensource.box.com/spout/ it supports xlsx and ods, sadly no xls but it works with big files  without using more than 3MB of RAM for any file i use it and is very good , tough is good for reading files or writing those, if you need to format cells or color specific cells and not the whole row it lacks a bit form coloring and formatting cell styles is better php excel or its new version PhpSpreadsheet also this new version has support for .xls now but keeps the same memory trouble

Comment: PHP spout is a great library, but unfortunately it does not support basic features like column width configuration, xls loading (just xlsx) or excel template file loading.